# Connection problem if I enable "Cloned MAC Address" on my Wifi

Tags: wireless, networking, mac

My wlan0 "Device MAC address" is: OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO, in "Edit Connection" window "Cloned MAC address" was empty. I entered a new MAC address in this field: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX. and saved it. After that I am not able to connect o myssid!
I checked in my modem setting (using LAN cable). The MAC filtering is disabled in my modem.

This is output of `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` after trying to connect to myssid (with cloned MAC address).

```
Feb  1 23:30:05 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'myssid'
Feb  1 23:30:05 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Feb  1 23:30:05 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Feb  1 23:30:05 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Feb  1 23:30:05 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): taking down device.
Feb  1 23:30:05 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): set MAC address to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop kernel: [262160.604817] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop kernel: [262160.604834] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop kernel: [262160.605022] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> disabled
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'myssid' has security, but secrets are required.
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disabled -> inactive
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'myssid' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'myssid'
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop wpa_supplicant[1383]: message repeated 3 times: [ wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED ]
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop wpa_supplicant[1383]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm (SSID='myssid' freq=2412 MHz)
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop kernel: [262161.475402] wlan0: authenticate with mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop kernel: [262161.476572] wlan0: send auth to mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm (try 1/3)
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop kernel: [262161.478407] wlan0: authenticated
Feb  1 23:30:06 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Feb  1 23:30:11 my-laptop kernel: [262166.474938] wlan0: deauthenticating from mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm by local choice (reason=3)
Feb  1 23:30:11 my-laptop wpa_supplicant[1383]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="myssid" auth_failures=1 duration=10
Feb  1 23:30:11 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Feb  1 23:30:21 my-laptop wpa_supplicant[1383]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Feb  1 23:30:21 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Feb  1 23:30:22 my-laptop wpa_supplicant[1383]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="myssid"
Feb  1 23:30:22 my-laptop wpa_supplicant[1383]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm (SSID='myssid' freq=2412 MHz)
Feb  1 23:30:22 my-laptop kernel: [262177.257358] wlan0: authenticate with mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm
Feb  1 23:30:22 my-laptop kernel: [262177.259481] wlan0: send auth to mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm (try 1/3)
Feb  1 23:30:22 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Feb  1 23:30:22 my-laptop kernel: [262177.260940] wlan0: authenticated
Feb  1 23:30:27 my-laptop wpa_supplicant[1383]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="myssid" auth_failures=2 duration=20
Feb  1 23:30:27 my-laptop kernel: [262182.258511] wlan0: deauthenticating from mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm by local choice (reason=3)
Feb  1 23:30:27 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Feb  1 23:30:31 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long, failing activation.
Feb  1 23:30:31 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> failed (reason 'SSID not found') [50 120 53]
Feb  1 23:30:31 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for connection 'myssid'
Feb  1 23:30:31 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Feb  1 23:30:31 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Feb  1 23:30:31 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): taking down device.
Feb  1 23:30:31 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): reset MAC address to OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO
Feb  1 23:30:31 my-laptop kernel: [262186.002396] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
Feb  1 23:30:31 my-laptop kernel: [262186.002412] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
Feb  1 23:30:31 my-laptop kernel: [262186.002596] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  1 23:30:31 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> disabled
Feb  1 23:30:31 my-laptop wpa_supplicant[1383]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Feb  1 23:30:31 my-laptop NetworkManager[3800]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disabled -> inactive
```

If I set cloned MAC address empty or equal to device MAC address, I could connect to myssid without any problem.

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to change mac address the simplest wey is to use command

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 hw ether  xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - represent "new" mac address

Comment: In edit connection, I could assign a MAC address separately for each connection. There is a question about commands you suggested: which connection's MAC address is changed? and is this change permanent?

Comment: Change is not permanent and for wlan0 interface is. For your wifi card.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, though. Either the GUI is the same as the command & is broken (or being used incorrectly) -- or the GUI is doing something different. Interested to know, having the same issue.