# What is the difference between "Cloned MAC address" in "Edit Connection" GUI and ifconfig command?

Tags: wireless, networking, mac, clone, ifconfig

I found that there are at least two methods to assign a spoofed MAC address to my network connection:

1. Assign a MAC address to a connection using "Edit connection" GUI in WiFi (or Ethernet) tab inside "Cloned MAC address" edit box.
2. Assign a MAC address to wlan0 using ifconfig command:

   ```
   sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
   sudo ifconfig wlan0 hw ether  xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
   sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
   ```

Now, my question is, what is the difference between these two ways?

Comment: There is another question about "Cloned MAC address" that may help to answer this question or help someone in other way: http://askubuntu.com/questions/580611/connection-problem-if-i-enable-cloned-mac-address-on-my-wifi

Comment: If you know the answer to this question you may know the answer to following question as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/580874/is-there-any-command-line-equivalent-for-edit-connection-gui

Answer (score 0):

Edit connection is actually `nm-connection-editor` applet, which probably calls ifconfig for you. With ifconfig method, you're changing MAC directly

Comment: But there is an obvious difference between these two methods: Edit connection changes the MAC address only for the specified connection and `ifconfig` changes MAC address for the adapter independent of which connection is used!