# Is there any command line equivalent for "Edit Connection" GUI?

Tags: wireless, networking, command-line, mac

I found that there are at least three methods to assign a spoofed MAC address to my network connection:
Method (1): Assign a MAC address to a connection using "Edit connection" GUI in WiFi (or Ethernet) tab inside "Cloned MAC address" edit box.

and Method (2): Assign a MAC address to wlan0 using ifconfig command:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 hw ether  xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Method (3): Using [**macchanger**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AnonymizingNetworkMACAddresses) package.

Now, my question is: "is there any command line equivalent for method (1)"?

Comment: If you know the answer to this question you may the answer to following question as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/580863/what-is-the-difference-between-cloned-mac-address-in-edit-connection-gui-and

Comment: And there is another question that is related to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/580611/connection-problem-if-i-enable-cloned-mac-address-on-my-wifi

Answer (score 2):

Since the first method is using Network Manager, and the Network Manager command-line interface ([`nmcli`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/nmcli.1)) doesn't support it, no.

Comment: @php-learner: It's niot because you don't like the answer that you should forget to click the grey check-mark under the abysmally small number at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)